# How to make a continuous time signal in MATLAB to use in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I want a trajectory to be created in MATLAB, but I am unable to find how can I make this function continuous.The function is

```
fsg=abs((sign(t-a)-sign(t-b))/2), and the trajectories are  x=t.*fsg(t,0,20)+20.*fsg(t,20,40)+(60-t).*fsg(t,40,60)
, y=(t-20).*fsg(t,20,40)+ 20.*fsg(t,40,60)
```

and

```
z=0
```

How can I create it, because my model is continuous and I want to give continuous input to it. What i had done is: I created fsg function in MATLAB and created time t=[0:.1:80]. Then, I calculated x,y,z and then created a timeseries variant of these to give them as input to my model.

Comment: That seems like a good approach. You can then use the From Workspace block to get the data into the Simulink model as input.

Comment: but my model is showing an error in the integrator block

Comment: Then you need to share your model with us so that we can replicate the issue. Right now, you don't provide us witj nearly enough information.

Comment: this is a quadrotor model and i am using simulink to simulate it if you are interested i can send you the model.

Comment: No. Don't send your model to me. What you need to do is edit your question and add all the information necessary to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It doesn't have to be your complete model, but enough to reproduce the issue, including any data needed to run the model. You can put links to filesharing sites for people to download model and/or data files, script files, etc...